# Can't access plumber API with public IP

Tags: r, rstudio, digital-ocean, plumber

Problems with accessing the public API hosted on digitalocean.com

I have been struggling with the R lib Plumber to generate a web API from RStudio. I manage to deploy a local API with swagger at `http://127.0.0.1:8002/__swagger__/` which works fine. I also managed to install a droplet with `plumber::do_deploy_api` and a nginx webserver which I can access through my browser. SSH works great as well from Rstudio and the keygen is saved in `id_rsa`.

When deploying my API-folder to DigitalOcean with `plumber::do_deploy_api` I get a response saying that the server is up and running on port 8000. I have open up HTTP to port 80 in the firewall settings, but can’t access the API altough it’s deployed.

When logged in to my server with SSH I can do `curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/__swagger__/` which gives me the HTML-code so it’s there, but still I can’t access my `plumber.R` file API from the browser? `http://138.68.xx.xx:8000/plot` gives me ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Any recommendations on how to proceed?

Comment: "open up HTTP to port 80" 80 or 8000?

Comment: Thanks, I can only open 80 as a HTTP port on Digital Ocean, tried open 8000 as custom type under firewall settings but still no success, even tried removing my firewall, still no luck.